# Google Simple API key stopped working

Tags: api, google-api, google-plus

I'm using Python/Twisted to do asynchronous HTTP calls to the Google+ API. Our client app passes over the user's access_token and we do an API call to...

```
https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/?%s&key=%s&
```

... where %s and %s are being filled with a valid access_token and (supposedly) valid Simple API Key, respectively.

Everything was working beautifully yesterday. Today I continued to work on the unit tests for this when the API suddenly started returning:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "keyInvalid",
    "message": "Bad Request"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Bad Request"
 }
}
```

usageLimits, keyInvalid... Okay, I get it. I've seemingly hit the usage limits and they have invalidated API keys coming from this account. Except, I haven't...

The "Courtesy Limit" is supposed to be "10,000 requests/day", yet I've only made a couple hundred calls (according to Google's own usage graphs), and I am still seeing "0% used" on the quotas tab.

I would have brought this to Google directly, but they seem to have dropped their Developers Google Group in favor of a Google+ discussion that doesn't actually receive any responses.

Any help or guidance is extremely appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer was quite simple! You can't send both the access_token and the key in the same API call. If you use the access_token you're authenticating the API call as the user, if you use your projects Simple API Key you're authenticating as yourself. If you use both, the call fails.

Comment: Can you file a bug report about that here: https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/list

Comment: [Issue #604](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=604)

Answer (score 7):

Just so we are clear, you are using your key from your [Google API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/) page? On there you should see a tab for "API Access" near the top left hand corner of the page. Make sure that the API Key you are using is your `Key for browser apps (with referers)` Key, otherwise it won't work.

At any rate, an API Call for me looks like this:

https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/114789529333378876576?key=ENTER_YOUR_KEY_HERE

You should be able to make at least one API Call per day without a valid Key.

Answer (score 3):

This took me quite a long time to figure out, so hope to save some time to someone else :)

Take a look at thi spost, by google staff (in 2012..) https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-ajax-search-api/HuKhXfsoMQc

> Sorry for the delayed response.  This error (which we're working on improving the descriptiveness of) also occurs when you have a
>   restriction on your key (e.g. locked to a specific referer or IP
>   address).  Please confirm that if you've set such a restriction in the
>   APIs Console, that the referer or IP address that you're making the
>   requests from.  Pay special attention to any wildcards used on the
>   referer - for instance, if you use *.abc.com, it won't work if your
>   request comes from "yoururl".

also would have been great if google team fixed this issue! :)

Comment: I have 0 restrictions and keep receiving this error

Answer (score 1):

In my case - I just had to wait few minutes because it was short time after updating my API KEY. Whenever you create a new key or update it on YT developer console. YT has up to 15 mins to make all the changes on their side

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a parameter named Key, so it thought that was an actual key, just renamed the parameter.