# Trying to run google API quickstart for gmail, followed all steps to the point but getting error

Tags: javascript, html, gmail, gmail-api

Trying to pull an attachment from an email using gmail API.
When attempting the quickstart (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/js) Im getting this error

I tried waiting in case the keys take some time to be valid however this did nothing, also tried new keys.

```
<pre id="content" style="white-space: pre-wrap;"></pre>

<script type="text/javascript">

  // Client ID and API key from the Developer Console

  var CLIENT_ID = 'MY ID';

  var API_KEY ='MY KEY'

  // Array of API discovery doc URLs for APIs used by the quickstart
  var DISCOVERY_DOCS = ["https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/gmail/v1/rest"];
```

This is the output im getting in the web browser.

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "usageLimits",
        "reason": "keyInvalid",
        "message": "Bad Request"
      }
    ],
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Bad Request"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems fairly similar to this problem -
[Google Simple API key stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17436940/google-simple-api-key-stopped-working)

Go to your API Key - 
https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials

In the API restrictions section check the radio button "Don't restrict key",
Or make sure to add Gmail API to the list or restricted API's.